# String, split. need help understanding

Tags: java, string, split

Case 1

```
String a = "         ";
String[] b = a.split(",");
System.out.println(b.length);
```

**Prints 1. Why?**

Case 2

```
String a = ",,,,,,,,,,,,";
String[] b = a.split(",");
System.out.println(b.length);
```

**Prints 0. Why?**

Honestly, i am at a loss here

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This behaviour is mentioned in the documentation for [String.split](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

> This method works as if by invoking the [two-argument split method](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array**.

Your first example should give an array containing a single string containing spaces. A string containing spaces is not empty so it is included in the result.

Your second example would give an array containing lots of empty strings, but these are not included in the resulting array as mentioned in the documentation.

As to why the Java designers decided that removing trailing empty strings when `limit` is zero is a good idea - I don't know. Most other programming languages / platforms do not do this. I consider it to be a "gotcha" - a feature that doesn't quite work as most people expect.

Comment: Note that if you you use `a.split(",", -1)` (or any negative), empty trailing components won't be removed.

Comment: The reason is that they wanted it to behave the same as perl.

Comment: All this weirdness is part of the reason Guava has its own Splitter class.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1 has a single item in the b array "          " - your spaces

Case 2 empty entries are being removed

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2005
my db name:a
table name:a
column name:a(varchar(max)),b(int)
values

a                                           b

hello|howdoudo|imfine|thanks                1
h|ho|ine|ths                                2
helddlo|howdddoudo|imfiddne|tdhs            3

tell me the split stored procedure to get the table looks like this for i.e., when
b=1                b=2              b=3

output              output           output
a                  a                a 
hello              h                helddlo
howdoudo           ho               howdddoudo
imfine             ine              imfiddne
thanks             ths              tdhs